# JavaScript files randomly break?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I finished my [site](http://avuedesigns.com) a month ago and everything has been working great. I have not updated anything in the backend since launch. Today I go to view it and I notice some of the javascript was not running.

When I look through firebug I notice 5 javascript files all of a sudden have problems with `Uncaught TypeError` But i never touch them, and everything was running perfect 2 days ago. What could cause this?

Comment: Any chance you're using jQuery with the CDN always pushing the latest version?

Comment: Yeah... jQuery 1.9 removed the support for `$.browser` that several of your plugins use.

Comment: You're loading jQuery twice. And the second is v1.9 `/*! jQuery v1.9.0 | (c) 2005, 2012 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using two jquery.js (different versions), Try to use only the most current, updated and use plugins too.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.0'></script>
```

1- try validating your HTML.

2- Avoid unnecessary plugins.

3- Follow these practices:
http://blog.monitis.com/index.php/2011/05/15/30-tips-to-improve-javascript-performance/

Comment: Thank you. I thought I disabled the google CDN. Always need fresh eyes. Thank you once again.